# OptionMenu does not show anything

Tags: android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // mEditor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    Log.d("sayem", "onCreateOptionMEnu");

    return true;

}
```

And this is my menu.xml file path res/menu/menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/settings_shortcut"
    android:icon="@drawable/violet"
    android:title="@string/settings_label"
    android:visible="true"/>
```

It does not show any kind of menu as expected.

Comment: Just so you are aware. This is not a forum where you just delete a post and then repost it so that your post is at the top of list. Be careful, people will spank you for this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [OptionMenu does not show....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168284/optionmenu-does-not-show)

Comment: @Bryan your comment is senseless. If you have time, answer or comment, otherwise don't. A comment about "I will do it later after ..." doesn't help anybody and is an information that doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html), the menu.xml file (or game_menu.xml file) has an outer tag called `<menu>`. I don't see that in yours.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Either you have not posted your full menu.xml, or it isn't formed as it should be.

Comment: It is in his original post. This is a duplicate post of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168284/optionmenu-does-not-show

Comment: Please delete this post, since you already have a question out there for this.